# linked server to connect to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I am using a SQL Server 2016 Standard edition 64-bit Operating System located in AWS. I want to create a linked server to connect to Oracle.

I used the following T-SQL statement:

```
USE [master]
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
            @server = N'ServerName', 
            @srvproduct=N'Oracle', 
            @provider=N'ORAOLEDB.ORACLE', 
            @datasrc=N'ServerName', 
            @provstr=N''

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
            @rmtsrvname=N'ServerName',
            @useself=N'False', 
            @locallogin=NULL,
            @rmtuser=N'UserName',
            @rmtpassword='UserPassword'  
GO
```

Once I create the linked server and open the catalog folder the server hangs. When I call a table from the linked server using the openquery, the server hangs as well.

This is my first time creating a linked server using T-SQL. I will appreciate any help here.

Comment: Notice the coloring on your 2nd EXEC, It all turns red because you are missing a delimiter after 'False ...  Is that a typo, or is that the problem?

Comment: Have you installed Oracle client on your SQL server box and configured it (ora TNS, etc)?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It was definitely a typo. I did install the Oracle client on my SQL Server box and configured the tnsname.ora file

Comment: after the oracle client install, you need to restart the services (sometimes its easier to just reboot the server)...a good way to test after that if its working would be to go to your data sources window in the server and see if you can create an oracle data source there before you try the one in sql server...then next try it from management studio using the GUI tool from the server...I did this very recently for a sharepoint bcds oracle integration

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Thanks for the feedback. I have tried it and I was not able to connect to the oracle server. On the other hand, I am able to connect to the oracle server via the sqldeveloper using the same credentials I am using to create the oracle data source. Not sure why I am not able to create an oracle data source.

Comment: you might need to regsvr32 the ole dll (itll have a file name starting with oraole)...that doesnt happen automatically...after that will require another restart of the sql server services

Comment: This is an update to the solution I found and everything is working fine now. The oracle server is located remotely and the ms sql in AWS; therefore, I had to Whitelist oracle's IP Address and port and do the same on the oracle remote server environment.

Comment: @Ctznkane525  Also, following your suggestion regarding performing a test with the oracle client helped me to identify that the IP Address and port needed to be whitelisted. Thank you so much!!